# SQL syntax error in absurdly simple sql?

Tags: python, mysql, prepared-statement, named-parameters

Calling:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO standard_group (group_name, subject, grade, country, state) VALUES (%(group_name), %(subject), %(grade), %(country), %(state));
```

With

```
('Arizona Social Studies Standards', 'Social Studies', '1', 'United States', 'AZ')
```

eg:

```
    print group_columns
    print group_sql
    print group
    cur.execute(group_sql, dict(zip(group_columns, group)))
```

But I always get:

```
['group_name', 'subject', 'standard_category', 'standard_sub_category', 'standard_name', 'standard_description', 'grade', 'country', 'state', 'is_common_core', 'is_state_standard']
INSERT IGNORE INTO standard_group (group_name, subject, grade, country, state) VALUES (%(group_name), %(subject), %(grade), %(country), %(state));
('Arizona Social Studies Standards', 'Social Studies', '1', 'United States', 'AZ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "standards-import/simport.py", line 167, in <module>
    cur.execute(group_sql, dict(zip(group_columns, group)))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 507, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 722, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 640, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%(group_name), %(subject), %(grade), %(country), %(state))' at line 1
```

I've tried with named params, `?` and `%s`, and get

- Not all arguments used
- Wrong number of arguments for named parameter
- SQL syntax

**What's going on?? What am I missing???**

Comment: When you use `%(group_name)` shouldn't the substitutions be in a dictionary rather than a list?

Comment: `dict(zip(group_columns, group))` turns them into a dict (with the right key names). Something else is also still the issue, because I can't do list + `%s` or `?` format, either.

Comment: Can you paste your python script so we can look at indents and such?

Comment: Source code: http://pastebin.com/8SwsuNF6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a small typo. You forgot to add `s` to the params

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO standard_group (group_name, subject, grade, country, state) VALUES (%(group_name)s, %(subject)s, %(grade)s, %(country)s, %(state)s);
```

The relevant code is here:

- [`execute(self, operation, params=None, multi=False)`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/cursor.py#L460)
- [`_process_params_dict(self, params)`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/cursor.py#L351)

Comment: This inserts, sort of, but I get rows that look like: http://cl.ly/image/0l1l2d3V181o -- Where is this documented? I'm getting confused between docs for Mysql, Mysql-python, and mysqldb which all do this differently.

Comment: Your `def row_to_group_values(row)` returns string, not list. When you `zip` it with `group_columns` you get what you see.

Comment: I'm a big dummy. Thanks guys.